# Cassandra inter data center communication broken

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have two data enters DC1 and DC2. Both communicate via a private link. Yesterday, we had a problem with a private link for 10 mins. From the time the problem was resolved, nodes in both data centers are not able to communicate with each other. When I do a nodetool status on a node in DC1, the nodes in DC2 are stated as down. When tried in DC2, nodes in DC1 are shown as down .

But in the cassandra logs, we can clearly see that handshaking is failing every 5 seconds for communication between data centres. At TCP level, there are too many fin_wait1 generated by cassandra which is still a puzzle . Closed_wait top transitions due to this is very high. Due to this kind of problem of TCP listen drops, we moved from 2.0.1 to 2.0.3. In 2.0.1, it was within data center itself. But here it's between data centers. If it has anything to do with the snitch configuration, I am using GossipingPropertyFileSnitch.

This clearly started happening post private link failure. Any idea on this?

Cassandra version used is 2.0.3

Comment: Can you telnet on the cassandra storage port from the node in one DC to the other DC?

Comment: On the network side , everything seems to be fine. The two nodes are trying to establish a TCP communication at the network layer. Cassandra doesn't complete the application level handshaking. I made a rolling restart of all servers and it is working fine now. But my concern is another private link failure which is quite common . Can't be doing a restart of all cassandra nodes whenever this happens. Cassandra must have a mechanism of detecting and reconnecting as the retries do continue at every 5 second interval.

Comment: Am discussing the same over here in jira too - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6772